# AKKA Get request for Client Side, Future Incomplete Error

Tags: scala, rest, akka-http

I am trying to Get Response from a URL in the JSON Payload using AKKA Http. Though using Postman I could able to see the JSON output but using Intellij my code always shows a message that FUTURE .

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink
import akka.util.ByteString




case class param(name:String,modelerType:String,ApplicationNotFoundExceptionNumOps:String,ApplicationNotFoundExceptionAvgTime:String)

  case class Payload(beans:List[Param])


  object JsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {

    implicit val param=jsonFormat4(Param)
    implicit val payload = jsonFormat1(Payload)
  }

  object Test extends App  {

    import JsonProtocol._
    implicit val system = ActorSystem("RM")
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    import system.dispatcher

    val responseFuture:Future[HttpResponse] =
      Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri="http://url/jmx"))



    responseFuture.onComplete {

      case Success(v) => Unmarshal(v.entity.toStrict(5
        seconds)).value.map{_.data.utf8String.parseJson.convertTo[Payload]


        case Failure(f)=> println("Failed to connect "+f)
      }

    }
```

Comment: I get the below message in the output                                                                        
  GET /jmx Empty -> 200 OK Chunked                                                                                                      Future(<not completed>)

Comment: did you solved this issue ?